# Is it possible to create a template template parameter list?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, template-templates

I was wondering whether it's possible to make a list containing template template parameters, like

```
template <
    template <typename...> class TTP0,
    template <typename...> class... TTPs
>
struct TTP_List : TTP_List<TTPs...> {};
```

A problem I encountered is that I did not know a good way to access the elements of the list, that is, `TTP0`. I would like to use type aliases, `typedef` or `using`. I however know this is not possible, because the template template parameters are not types and must therefor not be treated as such.

A approach I could imagine working is making explicit structs to read the data and make it use specializations, such as:

```
template <template <typename...> class>
struct container_TTPs;

template <template <typename...> class TTP>
struct container_TTPs<std::vector> {};
```

However, this approach seems very explicit. Is there a way to accomplish this recognition without this use of template specialization?

Feel free to ask if I need to elaborate.

EDIT: For example, I want to be able to use certain expressions for every held type, such as `TestClass<TTP_List<std::vector, std::list>>::value`, where `TestClass` uses the std::vector and the std::list, without requiring a variadic template within `TestClass`, so that multiple `TTP_List`s can be passed.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand what do you mean with "access the elements of the list".

It seems to me that you should give us an example of what do you want, concretely, do accessing elements of the list.

Anyway, as you can use `using` to "access" (?) typenames

```
template <typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct foo 
 { 
   using type = T0;
 };
```

you can use a template `using` to "access" (?) a template-template parameter as follows

```
template <template <typename...> class T0, 
          template <typename...> class ... Ts>
struct foo 
 { 
   template <typename ... As>
   using templ_type = T0<As...>;
 };
```

and you can use it in this way

```
// vi is a std::vector<int>
foo<std::vector, std::set, std::map>::templ_type<int> vi { 0, 1, 2 };
```

Comment: Note that at least some compilers break horribly when you feed a non-variardic template as `T0`, but only when you reach `templ_type`.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont - Sorry... I don't understand. Do you mean there is a defect in my example? Or in some compilers? How can I reproduce the horribly break?

Comment: I found your answer quite helpful - Thanks a lot. with "access" I'm trying to refer to the types held by the variadic template. I would like to make algorithms such as `find_TTP<std::vector>::value` valid, which would check whether std::vector is being held in the variadic template, and actually try to "access" it by saying something similar to `TTP0<T1, T2>::value`, in which T1 and T2 are extern types. This is, for example, done by template specialization, recognizing TTP0.

Answer (score 1):

The problem (a problem) is that a template parameter variadic list (isn't important if of typenames, of values or of template-templates) must be in last position.

So

```
template <typename ... Ts, typename T0>
struct foo 
 { };
```

is wrong, because `Ts...` must be in last position, and

```
template <typename T0, typename ... Ts>
struct foo 
 { };
```

is correct.

With template-template parameters,

```
template <template <typename ...> class ... Ts,
          template <typename ...> class T0>
struct foo 
 { };
```

is wrong where

```
template <template <typename ...> class T0,
          template <typename ...> class ... Ts>
struct foo 
 { };
```

is correct.

Comment: You're right - Thank you. I updated the post immediately when I read your reaction. I guess I wrote the example code a little to fast... However, this is not relevant for the problem I'm trying to show.